# jQuery click function not updating

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a slideshow plugin, however, when I try to navigate to the left and right the listener's that are attached to the controls aren't updating

```
$.fn.imageOverlay = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.click(function () {
            //load paramters and stuff

            $.ajax({
                //stuff
                success: function(data) {
                    loadOverlay(data);
                }
            });
        });

        var loadOverlay = function() {
            jQuery(document).on('click', '.rightCtrl', function () {
                var id = $(this).data('id');

                console.log(id);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: domain + "loadajax/get_photo_overlay",
                    data: { id: id, type: params.type, criteria: params.criteria },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        setData(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        };

        var setData = function (data) {
            $('.rightCtrl').attr('data-id', data.controls.right);
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

When I click on the div "rightCtrl" it fires but an old data-id is being used. While inspecting the html markup the attribute is updating, but the new values aren't being passed. The issues lies within the function loadOverlay:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.rightCtrl', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); //this is an outdated value
}
```

Comment: The second argument of `on` (_for event delegation_) should be string (_a selector_) not a jQuery object.

Comment: sorry when I was editting the code I subconsciously added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is difference between properties and attributes. jQuery's `.data()` method caches the values behind the scenes. It only reads the `data-*` attribute when there is no cached value for the specified property. For understanding the issue you can check this question: [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

You should be consistent, either use `.attr()` or `.data()` method.